# Weather API for Height & Density of Clouds

Tags: api, weather

I'm looking for an API that can provide the density and/or height of clouds in the sky given a city or coordinates. For instance, on a stormy day, I'd like to find how dense the storm cloud was and the height of it. I'd like something free but paid API's are just as good. So, requirement is:

- Either gives the density or height of a cloud in a given area
- It should produce something standard like JSON
- it'll be used in a Python project
- preferred "localization" of the data is English

Feature that aren't requirements but wanted a lot are:

- Provides both the density and height of a storm cloud in a given area
- Provides historical data
- Free

Comment: If you have any comments about way's to retrieve this data that aren't API's, it would be much appreciated if you comment about them.